# Problem using ProgressBar.setProgress(int)

Tags: android, progress-bar

08-18 11:24:09.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22649): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Is there any solution? :/

Answer (score 3):

Yes. 
You can't touch UI in non-UI threads, so the solution is to run the problematic code inside a `runOnUiThread`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your problematic code
    }
});
```

Comment: Can i make something like class doSync extends AsyncTask implements runOnUiThread?

Comment: what's the need for that? You can run this method inside the doInBackground()

Answer (score 3):

Only the UI thread can manipulate with views and stuffs. If you are working in another thread, try using `Handler` to post change to view to UI thread or switch to use `AsyncTask`

So you are using `AsyncTask` already, so you should `ProgressBar.setProgress()` inside `onProgressUpdate()` of `AsyncTask`. Override this method